# How to convert an Illustrator logo file for vinyl plotter

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vinyl

[image]

I'm in the process of creating a logo file that will be used for vinyl graphics. Never actually created such a file before, and I know some of the requirements for it, i.e. that anywhere you see a path is where the plotter will cut. But I'm not sure how to get this file to where it needs to be – will the plotter only cut around the outline if I create a badge kind of logo, or cut through everything i.e. also through the paths inside the badge area?

Comment: Have you spoked to the production provider and asked what their requirements are?

Comment: No – this is a freelance project and I'm just creating the file, but I don't know who they will be going through. I don't think they even have anyone lined up yet, its just something they're planning on doing later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a layer above your artwork and name it cutline. The thickness of the path doesn't matter. Any path in the cutline layer will then be cut.

So if the thick black line on the outside is the only path in the cutline layer then only the outside of the graphic will be cut. It is up to you if you want just the outside to be cut or part of the inside as well.

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect. Didn't know it could be that simple.